# How can I set my Java system look and feel for JNLP apps?

Tags: java, swing, gtk, look-and-feel, jnlp

I am running Gnome on OpenSuse. As a result, my system look and feel is GTK+, which has numerous ugly problems (see some of them [here](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/campbell/archive/2007/02/swing_and_gtk_w_1.html)).

During development of my swing app, I can run the client from command line or IDE and specify VM parameter

> -Dswing.systemlaf=com.sun.javax.swing.plaf.metal.CrossPlatformLookAndFeel

to make it look good.

But I don't know how to force Java Webstart to use this VM parameter when I start the application through JNLP.

**edit:**
This has nothing to do with the programmatic ability to set the look & feel. The application does this properly.

My question is how to tell Java Webstart to use a VM parameter "swing.systemlaf" when it runs the myapp.jnlp file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java Web Start allows certain JVM flags to be set with the java-vm-args attribute of the j2se element 
but you may use

```
<property name="key" value="overwritten"/>
```

and set properties. it will be available through the System.getProperty and System.setProperties methods

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#resources

Answer (score 2):

You can always use `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());`

Comment: No, I need to tell Java Webstart to set the VM property when I fire up the myapp.jnlp file.

Comment: (`getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName() `)

Comment: Just updated my question to clarify that this is not programmatic setting/getting of the look & feel, but rather, how to tell Java Webstart to use a VM property (swing.systemlaf) when I execute the JNLP file.

Answer (score 1):

I know this subject is quite old now but it may be useful.

You can force the look and feel with the following environment variable:

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dswing.systemlaf=com.sun.javax.swing.plaf.metal.CrossPlatformLookAndFeel"
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can configure properties in WebStart using the `-userConfig` command line option. The WebStart dialgos are part of the JRE installation, and not part of the application.