# Force osx compatible LookAndFeel in legacy jar using com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel

Tags: java, macos, swing, jnlp, look-and-feel

There's a jnlp-program/file I'd like to use that points to a jar that was built to use com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel. I'm on a osx machine here. The program hangs. Sad smiley. Facepalm. Etc.

Is there any way to modify the jnlp so that I can force something like the Metal look and feel?

I guess I could manually download all the jars, unjar them, decompile the files with Windows look and feel, sed some, recompile, repackage and run.. but that sounds.. Labor intensive. I'm looking for a quick fix here.

Comment: Hav a look at [How can I set my Java system look and feel for JNLP apps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252420/how-can-i-set-my-java-system-look-and-feel-for-jnlp-apps)

Comment: If the program is manually changing the look and feel, you may not be able to change it

Comment: WindowsLookAndFeel is developed to be runs only on WinOS(own key, mouse events and bugs too), have look at some of custom L&F

Comment: Setting the PLAF is typically done in the main.  If that's the case with this app. figure out what it does in the main, and repeat that in your own main except that yours calls for `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());` that will work for Windows, and *might* work for OS X and *nix machines.  Why 'might'?  Because programmers silly enough to hard wire the PLAF might also not use layouts or call `pack()`..

Comment: It hardcodes the look and feel. It only uses the windows look and feel on certain specific panes. So the program actually runs fine until I try to access that specific pane.

Comment: *"It only use the windows look and feel on certain specific panes"*  It might be cheaper to write this GUI fresh, than fix the existing one.

Comment: It's not my app to start with. =/

Comment: BTW - be sure to add @mKorbel (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* a person of a new comment.

Comment: *"It's not my app to start with."*  Are you *licensed* to use it?  Do you host the app. from your own servers?  -- Edit.  Never mind, my bad.  I at first missed the part where this was for *personal use*.